# Setting camera view on ipyvolume gives different viewing angle than matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, voila

I am trying to make an interactive notebook (with `voila`) where I use `ipyvolume` for plotting a surface. However, I do not manage to set the camera correctly with  `ipyvolume`. It should be a top-down view onto the z-direction. It works fine in the `matplotlib` case, but setting the same angle in `ipyvolume` does give me some 45º view. How can I get it to show the top down view?

If there is another way to achieve that, that's also be ok (needs to work in `voila` and be able to dynamically update the X, Y, Z and color data).

##### make data

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import ipyvolume as ipv

g = np.linspace(-np.pi/2, np.pi/2, 10)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(g, g, indexing='ij')
Z = np.sin(X**2+Y**2)
```

#### the `ipyvolume` plot

```py
fig1 = ipv.figure()
mesh = ipv.plot_surface(X, Z, Y)
ipv.show()
ipv.pylab.view(90,-90)
```

[image]

#### the matpotib pot

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.view_init(90, -90)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you swapped `Y` and `Z` by accident in `mesh = ipv.plot_surface(X, Z, Y)`, that could explain why you don't get the view you want. Once you make that change, the default view for `ipyvolume` (which is `ipv.pylab.view(0,0)`) appears to be the view you want. See code below, tested on google colab:

```py
fig1 = ipv.figure()
mesh = ipv.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
ipv.show()
```

And the output gives:

[image]

Comment: On top of that, you can use `ipv.view(0,0,distance)` to control the distance from your camera to your plot.

Comment: yes, you were right, the `X,Z,Y` was mixed up. Indeed the `ipv.view(0,0)` gets the direction correct. But you see that your figure still looks quite different compared to my matplotlib view. I tried increasing the distance, but it behaves very strange: e.g. `ipv.pylab.view(0, -1, 30)` should be very similar to `ipv.pylab.view(0, 0, 30)` (just 1 degree difference) but they look completely different for me. Is there a way to get the perspective similar to matplotlib?

Comment: The difference in the way the figure looks only comes form the distance from th ecamera to the plot. ```mesh = ipv.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
ipv.pylab.view(0,0,6)
ipv.show() ``` gives me a very similar result than the graph with matplotlib.

Comment: In my case, `ipv.pylab.view(0, -1, 30)` and `ipv.pylab.view(0, -1, 30)` do actually look very similar. I am using google colab